# Which package/method is used for this table?

Tags: tables

Whould love to know which package and method is used for this table.The figure is from Schlicht R. (2022) - The microtype package Subliminal refinements towards typographical perfection.

[image: Image from Schlicht R. (2022) - The microtype package Subliminal refinements towards typographical perfection.]

Comment: the tex source for the packge documentation is in the distribution, so most likely already on your machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did not know about dtx files before.